# Include tagged .org into another .org file

Tags: elisp, org-mode

I use org capture to write a work logbook (work-logbook.org, datetree), i also capture callouts and nightshifts.

In my work.org i have a monthly todo "communicate extra work like callouts"

Is it possible to get all :CALLOUT: Tagged entrys from one month out of the work-logbook file into the work.org file?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by your question?  Copy all :CALLOUT: tagged entries into work.org or do you just want to see them in the agenda/in an agenda view?

Comment: I want to copy all :CALLOUT: tagged entrys from work-logbook.org from this (or maybe last) month under my todo item in work.org, so i can export my todo item and send it to my boss :)

Edit: I'm also not sure if that's the best way to archive this ;-)